# Are there any alternatives to `eval` and `Kernel.const_get`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need to create an object from its name from as a string (ie. a value in some JSON). I know I can use:

```
classname = 'MyClass' 
eval classname
```

and the much better:

```
classname = 'MyClass'
obj = Kernel.const_get(classname)
```

but since this is Ruby I was wondering if there were other alternatives (and perhaps more subjectively elegant ways) to achieving this goal.

Comment: What is your context? Do you receive arbitrary strings or is there a limited number of valid inputs? Also, is there any particular reason (besides the "elegance" you mention) for your desire to avoid `const_get`?

Comment: No, no problem. I was just curious if there was a better alternative. Faster, perhaps?

Comment: For arbitrary strings, I doubt. Maybe with more constraints (only from a set of classes, only subclasses of a given class, only classes that include a module etc) we can think of alternatives

Comment: Its a shame you did submit as an "answer" or I would have ticked it as correct. I've done a tonne of research and there is another way to do it, but its roughly 3 x slower than using 'eval' (hardly a viable 'alternative'. I guess my answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've scoured the net, and the short answer is "no".

There is however a `Kernel#qualified_const_get` [written by a "Gregory"](http://redcorundum.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/kernelqualifiedconstget.html) which is kinda neat since it can get nested classes, but this obviously isn't native Ruby.

I found that little snippet from an awesome blog "Electric Sheep" by Sidu Ponnappa - who has done a magnificent writeup on using all three methods "[Loading classes from strings in Ruby](http://blog.sidu.in/2008/02/loading-classes-from-strings-in-ruby.html#.U0TILcdPikx)" - the conclusion being:

> Here are three choices when trying to convert a string to the
>   corresponding class:  Kernel#const_get, eval and
>   Kernel#qualified_const_get
>
> 1. Kernel#const_get is the fastest, doesn't handle nested classes and
>      works for all but the weirdest of scenarios (the class you're trying
>      to get hold of isn't a named constant)
> 2. eval is significantly slower, but it works in any situation
> 3. Kernel#qualified_const_get is abysmally slow, but handles nested
>      classes. However, until there is a native implementation, it loses to
>      eval on every front